# Toggle function conditional on window size

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a function where, if the window size is less than 768px, then I want to toggle the display of the given div using the link.

If the window size is greater than 768 I want the display to reset to block.

```
if($(window).width() < 768){
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);


       if( e.style.display == 'block' )
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }

}
else{
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('sidebar');"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Comment: `$('#el_id').toggle( $(window).width() < 768 )`

Comment: I want it so if the width is greater than 768, then display = block no matter what. Is the width is less than 768, it can be toggled.

Comment: @adeneo comment does the same, i wish can can double like his comment check my answer also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring that function  not calling it any where

Further more, you can use jquery and make it easy like:

```
 function toggle_visibility(id) {
  if($(window).width() < 768){
      $("#"+id).toggle();

  }
   else{
        $("#"+id).hide()
    }     

    }
```

Comment: look at the included html

Comment: This works, but when I toggle the div off and make the window large again, the div isn't there. I'm trying to make it so it's there if the window is larger than 768 no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

and where u calling function??

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);


   if( e.style.display == 'block' )
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
};
 if( $(document).width() < 768){
    toggle_visibiliti(your element id);
 }else{
   e.style.display = 'block';
  };
```